# What CAD software is this?

Tags: cad, software

In Rocket Lab's presentation video, [at around 00:21](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eZE043cKcD4&t=21s), you can see some engineer work with CAD software. Here's a screenshot:

[image: CAD software used by Rocket Lab]

Can anyone recognize which software they're using? Asking for a friend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the hint comes from the tab that says SOLIDWORKS in the left column, near the top of the block of actions. It's not visible in this screen shot, but is clearly visible in the video linked in the post.

Comment: Well it certainly looks like solidworks in the picture too.

Comment: It is 100% SolidWorks, although can't tell what year exactly it has the grey/blue colour scheme which I believe was introduced in 2017 iirc?